# C++ Overflow error when iterating backwards over last n-elements of vector with size 1

Tags: c++

I was doing some C++11 coding and kept getting a peculiar error when trying to iterate backwards over the last n elements of a vector, and the vector happened to have only one element in it.

The most basic version of the code is here:

```
vector<int> vec{7};
int n = 1;
for(int i = vec.size() - 1; i >= vec.size() - n; --i) {
    // do something with i and vec[i]
}
```

This works for any case where vec has size greater than 1. However, running the code given above throws an overflow error at runtime, which is caused by accessing the vector with an index of -1. I tried printing the value of i and vec.size() - n in the loop, and have verified both values to be -1 and 0 respectively, at the iteration throwing the error. The boolean expression (i >= vec.size() - n) evaluates to true in the loop however, while (i >= 0) still evaluates to false. I'm fairly certain there isn't a namespace error. Maybe this is some weird typecasting error where -1 is evaluated as an unsigned? Can't think of any other explanation.

Comment: use reverse iterators. `vec.size()` is unsigned, hence `vec.size() -1` is wrong.

Comment: Are you aware of what type of `vec.size()` is? Do you know `int i` is not of a suitable type for vector indexes? Do you know about reverse iterators?

Comment: When an unsigned integer underflows, (wraps below zero) it becomes very large.

Comment: @273K Thanks, realized that vec.size() returns an unsigned. When I'm doing operations involving the actual index, I prefer to use an integer-like type instead of doing calculations with iterators though—would you recommend using something like size_t?

Comment: A common idiom with indices , here, would be `for ( size_t i {vec.size()}; i-- > 0; )`.

Comment: the current issue aside, when `n = 1` the loop with condition `i >= vec.size() - n;` has only a single iteration at most

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai realize this, in my actual code n takes various values which may or may not be 1 but was trying to simplify in the spirit of MRE's ;)

Comment: in the spirit of an example that uses a loop you could set `n` to 42 or some other value that makes the loop not obsolete ;)

Comment: fwiw, there is also `std::ssize` which returns a signed value

Comment: @user2533504 -- Your compiler didn't [warn you](https://godbolt.org/z/98KW9KTav) about mixing signed and unsigned types?

Answer (score 0):

Did some more thinking and found out the answer, after remembering CS 101 stuff. vector.size() returns an unsigned integer, and everything in the expression `i >= vector.size() - n` is implicitly casted to unsigned. Thought I'd leave this up in case anyone else ran into this.